# Точная замена символа

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть строка вида: **2,12,55,29,22,10,28** или **12,55,29,22,10,2**

Каким образом заменить только цифру **2** ?

```
str_replace
```

меняет цифру 2 - везде. А нужно только там где она одна (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Другой вариант с регуляркой:

```
<?php
$s = '2,12,55,2,29,22,10,2';
echo preg_replace('/(?<!\d)2(?!\d)/', 'TWO', $s);
```

Использует [негативный просмотр](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4) назад `(?<!\d)` и вперед `(?!\d)`. В обоих случаях проверяется отсутствие цифры.

**UPD**

Для строки состоящей из цифр и запятых подойдет еще вариант с границей слов:

```
<?php
$s = '2,12,55,2,29,22,10,2';
echo preg_replace('/\b2\b/', 'TWO', $s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно попробовать такой вариант:

```
$str = '2,12,55,29,22,10,28';
$search = 2;
$replacement = 11111111;

$arr = explode(',', $str);
$str = implode(',', array_map(function($el) use ($search, $replacement) {
    return ($el == $search) ? $replacement: $el;
}, $arr));

echo $str;
```

Т.е. разделяем строку на составные части, далее пробегаем и изменяем нужный элемент на то, что хочешь, обратно склеиваем в строку.

Не самый эффективный способ, но всё-таки...

Answer (score 0):

С помощью **preg_replace** можно выбрать число, окружённое не цифрами(**\D**)

```
$s = '2,12,55,2,29,22,10,2';
echo preg_replace('/(^|\D)2(\D|$)/', '$1TWO$2', $s);
// TWO,12,55,TWO,29,22,10,TWO
```